# Preventing the resolving of non existent paths in categories with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, opencart

OpenCart store currently allows URL's to non existent locations to resolve and return a status 200 OK.

For example:-

```
http://www.domain.com/real-category
```

This allows anything after this path to load /real-category and return 200 OK and be indexed in Google such as:-

```
http://www.domain.com/real-category/456464564
http://www.domain.com/real-category/sdgsgsdsd
http://www.domain.com/real-category/type-anything-here-and-the-url-works
```

I have the following in `.htaccess` (amongst a lot of other rules which I don't think would be relevant to this query) and wish to know if there is something I can add to handle the above situation by returning a 404 not found error for non existent paths?

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^sitemap.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_sitemap [L]
RewriteRule ^googlebase.xml$ index.php?route=feed/google_base [L]
RewriteRule ^download/(.*) /index.php?route=error/not_found [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|js|css)
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?_route_=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Google indexer (nor any other indexer) has no purpose to follow URLs as `http://www.domain.com/real-category/sdgsgsdsd` unless they are present somewhere in the `href` attribute of `<a>` tag. So yes, it is not very nice from OpenCart but on the other hand crawlers (indexers) are following only the URLs present on Your website. Unfortunately, there is no way how to prevent this from `.htaccess` file, You only could implement such a behaviour into OpenCart directly to return 404 instead if the URL part cannot be identified.

Comment: Maybe You think of Google Analytics that is following all the URLs users are visiting on Your website - in this case, **yes**, google will log such a URL (`http://www.domain.com/real-category/sdgsgsdsd`) but only for Google Analytics purposes. It is not indexed for real - i.e. if I go search `sdgsgsdsd` in Google Your site won't show up. But it is true that in Your GA You should see that `/real-category/sdgsgsdsd` returned 404 HTTP status code instead of 200 OK.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question is. It's not immediately obvious how you want to "handle the above situation"? What would you like to happen?

Comment: @Dan: Question amended (return 404 errors for non existent paths) - seems it is a problem with OpenCart not handling this correctly.

Answer (score 0):

in first, lets understand how OC deals with Friendly URL'S:

in htaccess, this rule will generally be the entrypoint:
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?*route*=$1 [L,QSA]

the index.php instances some Action class on preAction array, one of these is `Action('common/seo_url')`. on his index method we have this code:

```
$parts = explode('/', $this->request->get['_route_']);

foreach ($parts as $part) {
    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "url_alias WHERE keyword = '" . $this->db->escape($part) . "'");

    if ($query->num_rows) {
        $url = explode('=', $query->row['query']);

        if ($url[0] == 'product_id') {
            $this->request->get['product_id'] = $url[1];
        }

        if ($url[0] == 'category_id') {
            if (!isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
                $this->request->get['path'] = $url[1];
            } else {
                $this->request->get['path'] .= '_' . $url[1];
            }
        }

        if ($url[0] == 'manufacturer_id') {
            $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'] = $url[1];
        }

        if ($url[0] == 'information_id') {
            $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';
    }
}

if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['manufacturer_id'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/manufacturer/info';
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['information_id'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'information/information';
}
```

Basically, this will get the last valid segment, on this preference order: product, category, manufacturer, info page. To solve your problem, you will need to check if has any invalid segment on the url. The simplest way i can imagine is checking the value of `'route'` index on `$this->request->get` array, if its equal `'error/not_found'` some segment isn't valid, then unset the valids segments results:

```
...
            $this->request->get['information_id'] = $url[1];
        }
    } else {
        $this->request->get['route'] = 'error/not_found';
    }
}

if(isset($this->request->get['route']) && $this->request->get['route'] == 'error/not_found'){
    unset($this->request->get['product_id'], $this->request->get['path'], $this->request->get['manufacturer_id'], $this->request->get['information_id']);
}

if (isset($this->request->get['product_id'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/product';
} elseif (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
    $this->request->get['route'] = 'product/category';
...
```

Quite simple, but with `rewrite rules` on .htaccess i think isn't possible...

[edit]

Please, dont edit core files on OC, instead use vQmod to add these lines before the check on `$this->request->get['product_id'])`.